# Web application currently running under Tomcat 6.0.35. I would need to test it under Tomcat 5.5.23, but it won't even let me add it

Tags: tomcat

I have changed hosting provider and they have CentOS. They install Tomcat 5.5 for free (already done) but ask for quite a bit of money to install Tomcat 6 or 7.

To decide I would need to test my application on my own box. It is currently running Tomcat 6.0.35, against 5.5.23.

I am quite confident that there is nothing that needs to be changed, or very little, to have it running. However, when I try to add my application to the 5.5.23, I get a pop up saying that "There are no applications that can be added or removed from the server".

I believe there is something somewhere in the project that can be changed so to at least try to run it?

I have kept 6.0.35 alongside the newly installed 5.5.23.

I have removed the application from the 6.0.23, and I still can't add it to the other one, because of that pop up message.

If, after the removal, I try to run the application, it is automatically added to 6.0.23 without asking me which one I would like.

What could be changed, to at least try to run it?

I use Eclipse Helios.

Comment: What's your method of deploying the app to the hosting providers's machine? I don't think you will get such error by droping the `war` file straight to the `webapp` folder. I'm not too familiar on how eclipse upload apps, but you might want to change your Eclipse dev server to tomcat 5.5.23 as well

Comment: I haven't deployed yet, I am moving from one provider with Tomcat 6 to another with Tomcat 5.5.23. I have installed it on my own box to test it, but I couldn't add my application to that version ( it was working fine with the original 6.0.35 ). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to change the project facet (in project properties) to Web Module 2.4 and the target runtime to Tomcat 5?

Comment: Stefan, I tried what you suggested ( thanks by the way ) but it didn't work.
However, the error which I got from that put me in the right direction.

In root there is a .settings directory.

I edited org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml and it worked.
`<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>`
became
`<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.4"/>`

And it did the trick for me.